# Nested Partials - Use Presenter Pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view that is getting very unruly. I'd like to move more of my view into other partials but this will result in nested partials...which I am wary of. I've heard of the presenter pattern and would like to implement it here but I don't know how to go about it. Specifically my row contain a do loop that I don't think I can extract easily. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="row">
  <h2>Applicant</h2>
  <%= render partial: 'people/summary', locals: { person: @applicant.identity } %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_person_path(@applicant.identity), class: "btn btn-info"%>
</div>

<%= render partial: 'divrow', locals: { var1: "Household members" } %>
<%= render partial: 'structure', locals: { path: "new_household_member_path" } %>


<div class="row">
  <h2>Residence history</h2>
  <% @applicant.residences.each do |r| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>
      <%= render partial: 'residences/summary', locals: { residence: r } %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_residence_path(r), class: "btn btn-info"%>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', r, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      </p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= render partial: 'structure', locals: { path: "new_residence_path" } %>

<div class="row">
  <h2>Income</h2>
  <% @applicant.incomes.each do |i| %>
    <p>
      <%= render partial: "incomes/summary", locals: { income: i } %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_income_path(i), class: "btn btn-info"%>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', i, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= render partial: 'structure', locals: { path: "new_income_path" } %>


<div class="row">
  <h2>Employment</h2>
  <% @applicant.employments.each do |e| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>
    <%= render partial: "employments/summary", locals: { employment: e } %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_employment_path(e), class: "btn btn-info"%>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', e, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= render partial: 'structure', locals: { path: "new_employment_path" } %>

<div class="row">
  <h2>Criminal history</h2>
  <% @applicant.criminal_histories.each do |e| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>
    <%= render partial: "criminal_histories/summary", locals: { criminal_history: e } %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_criminal_history_path(e), class: "btn btn-info"%>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', e, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= render partial: 'structure', locals: { path: "new_criminal_history_path" } %>
```

Comment: Why do you think its wrong to loop over partials?? I see a repetitive pattern, so that you can abstract it to a helper and pass the partial name and locals as parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, could you elaborate more on what the helper might look like? The module I'm attempting to write in the helper is convoluted (I'm using the following for guidance: http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-view-helpers-in-rails-4). At this point I'm thinking it just might be easier to create four separate partials: Residence, Income, Employment, and Criminal History and put the rows in there--it may not be the DRYest but I think it'd be the most comprehensible. Thoughts? Thanks again.